# `Array[i]` vs `Array+i`

Tags: c++, class, pointers

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Plane
{
    private:
        // data member
        string name;

    public:
        // constructor
        Plane();

        // destructor
        ~Plane();

        // member function
        void setName(string na);
};

int main()
{
    int num_plane;

    cout << "How many planes do you have? ";
    cin >> num_plane;

    Plane *p_to_plane = new Plane[num_plane];

    string name;
    for (int i = 0; i < num_plane; ++i)
    {
        cout << "The No. " << (i + 1) << " plane's name: ";
        cin >> name;

        (p_to_plane + i)->setName(name);
    }


    delete [] p_to_plane;

    system("Pause");

    return 0;
}
```

I have a question:

In main function, there is a `for` loop to add names to every plane.
However, if I write `p_to_plane[i]->setName(name)`, then an error happens.
The compiler asks me to write `p_to_plane[i].setName(name)`.

I cannot understand why. If it is `p_to_plane[i].setName(name)`, then `p_to_plane[i]` should be a class object. However, should it not be the pointer which points to the class object?

Additionally, I can't tell the difference between `p_to_plane[i]` and `p_to_plane + i`. Are they the same?

Comment: `p_to_plane[i]` is the same as `*(p_to_plane + i)`, not `p_to_plane + i`.

Comment: Thats an answer @George

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`a[b]` means `*(a + b)`. It's a dereference operation.

Similarly, `a->b` means `(*a).b`.

If `p` is a pointer to the first element of an array of objects, then you can access their methods using either of

1. `(*(p + i)).foo()`
2. `(p + i)->foo()`
3. `p[i].foo()`

In variant #2, the `->` operator is doing the dereferencing; in variant #3, the `[]` operator is doing the dereferencing.

(If you really want to combine them, you need something like `(&p[i])->foo()`, but that's just silly.)

Comment: Note that in general, "`a[b]` means `*(a + b)`" does not hold for user-defined types. For example, if `a` is `std::vector<int>`, then `a[b]` ≠ `*(a + b)`. +1 though :)

Comment: Yeah, for the purposes of this answer I'm completely ignoring operator overloading, which (for custom types) would let you arbitrarily redefine `*`, `+`, `[]`, and even `->`.

Answer (score 1):

`p_to_plane` is a `Plane*` (a pointer).

`*p_to_plane` dereferences that pointer, giving you a `Plane` (the first in the array).

`p_to_plane+i` increments that pointer, giving you an adjusted pointer to elsewhere in the array.

`*(p_to_plane+i)` deferences the adjusted pointer, giving you a `Plane` (the ith in the array).

`p_to_plane[i]` is the same as `*(p_to_plane+i)`.

So, the compiler is right: **`[]` has already done the dereference for you.**